# Array Dublicates data in sql

Tags: php, html, ajax

This is the HTML code

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<td> <input type="text" value=""  class="form-control" id="earn[]" name="earn[]"> 
<input type="hidden" value="123"  class="form-control" name="eid[]">
</td>
</tr>
```

and here is my code

```
include "settings/config.php";
$empid= trim(strip_tags($_POST['eid']));
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['earn']); $i++)
{
    $earnval = $_POST['eid'][$i];

    if (empty(trim($earnval))) continue;

    $updatepayrollearn=$conn->prepare("UPDATE  `emp_ern_cart` SET earnings='$earnval' WHERE empid='$empid'");
    $updatepayrollearn->execute();
    echo 'Data Updated';
}
```

The problem is, this code submit same data, let say the input data are (A,B,C) then the code submit (C,C,C)

Comment: You are updating _the same record_ multiple times, so of course only the last value “survives” after that.

Comment: Then how to fix this please

Comment: You need to use the same naming scheme for your eid hidden field - otherwise those values will all overwrite each other inside the POST data your script receives. And then you need to access that value _inside_ the loop as well, of course, and not once before it. And go read up on how to _properly_ do save & secure SQL queries - `trim(strip_tags(…))` is utmost nonsense. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it

Comment: `name="eid[]"` for those fields. And `$earnval = $_POST['eid'][$i];` _inside_ the loop.

Comment: Well, I got this error:  Notice: Array to string conversion